# Maximum Bitmap height and width Supported in Android

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I tried to get full size bitmap from drawable but not get.My image store into drawable folder and its sized 1082*1673 and when i get bitmap from drawable its sized 662*1024.

I tried to all possible changes

**My code shown below**

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.t_0001, o);
```

Comment: I tried to evary possible changes. But get bitmap evary time 1082*1673 sized..I create demo and i was seen in loagcat but get max to max 1024*1024 bitmap in android

Comment: Same sized 1082*1673 get images from drawable-nodpi.. My images is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p4ktqKCUi6cTwX6xVGNaDetrkWYkDcDA/view

Comment: i Try to using

 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.t_0001);

        int w = bmp.getWidth();
        int h = bmp.getHeight();

In Logcat width and height are correct but bitmap not properly get actual sized resolution

Comment: i tryied to create bitmap by 1025*1025 but not create bitmap

We create bitmap maximum 1024*1024 resolution in android
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 1025, 1025, false);

Comment: i want to need get full resolution type bitmap from drawable folder..Which i can't get from drawable... My Drawable images resolution is 1082*1673 But i get bitmap from drawable which resolution is 662*1024

Comment: I try and get bitmap from your images which send in URL. Please seen this 
 URL:-- https://pasteboard.co/I2sGrKQ.png

Comment: My Problem is i get images and convert drawable to bitmap which images resolution is down nothing else ...And this images mostly used in color fill..So the resolution down and pixel of images stretch the i can't fill color into images

Comment: Returned bitmap is low resolution so every pixel of image(bitmap) was stretch.So i can't used into my app.....My Default high resolution images are store into drawable folder so i want to get default drawable images